# Why having a carbonyl group is not contributing to binding energy

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs, medicinal-chemistry, molecular-dynamics

I am carrying out a virtual screening project for a protein receptor to identify possible ligands (small molecules). After the virtual screening, molecular dynamics, and MMGBSA calculation, I identified two ligands that differ only by one carbonyl group. Because this has not been published, I cannot disclose the structure. The MD study shows that the ligand **without** the carbonyl group is more stable over time (0-100ns). And MMGBSA calculation also shows that the one **without** the carbonyl group binds better.

From my understanding, having a carbonyl group should increase the likelihood of interacting with amino acids, and thus contributing to binding. I appreciate it if anyone could offer some possible reasons why this is the case (no carbonyl group is better). I asked GPT and it tells me it might be the steric effect which makes sense. Are there any further analyses I can do to answer this question?

By the way, I meant it to be a fully computational study, and thus I do not plan to validate it by wet lab.

Comment: Well, there could be various reasons. For example carbonyl could bind to another part of the ligand.

Comment: @Mithoron, are you suggesting that the carbonyl is binding to another part of the ligand, like an intra-molecule interaction?

Comment: Yeah. That's one option.

Comment: Without more details, impossible to say (and I do molecular dynamics for a living, looking at ligand-receptor interactions). However, binding free energies via MM-PBSA are going to at best be +/- 2 kcal/mol; and you haven't told us how you prepped the system (dealt with missing residues, protonation states of certain amino acids, and so on and so forth). The net of it is that your question is not answerable in the present state. As a side comment, if you are skilled enough to be running 100 ns MD and MM-PBSA analysis on the trajectories, you really should know more basic chemistry than you do.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt, thanks so much for the insight. I should have asked a better question with more details. I was just seeking some perspectives to look at the question and therefore your comment is already helpful to me! I will consult with my chemistry professors for more chemistry knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "From my understanding, having a carbonyl group should increase the
> likelihood of interacting with amino acids, and thus contributing to
> binding."

No. This is a fairly foundational misunderstanding, too. Think about it... all binding pockets consist of "amino acids," are you suggesting that having a carbonyl will always increase binding strength? No, of course not.

Protein-ligand is a much, much more complex phenomenon involving the steric and electrostatic impacts of each particular amino acid in the local binding area. I think you would be wise to focus your studies on basic biochemistry prior to beginning any drug development project.